# Ways for the differential equation $y' + {{y\ln(y)}\over x}= xy$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I've been stuck on one of my homework numbers. 
The number precise that the following equation is a non-linear equation of order 1 with x>0.

$$y' + {{y\ln(y)}\over x}= xy$$

So far, I tried 2 different methods to solve them. As suggested by internet (link below): Bernoulli, and as an inexact one. However, I get stuck every time.

[Bernoulli sample](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/ordinary-differential-equation-calculator/y'%2B%5Cfrac%7By%5Ccdot%20ln%5Cleft(y%5Cright)%7D%7Bx%7D%20%3D%20xy)

**As a small side note, can someone explain to me the following from the link: how, by passing ln(y) to the right side, we get y^1+1 ?

For the Bernoulli equation, when I try to solve it manually, I get in a kind of infinite integral, no matter how many time I integrate.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$y' + {{y\ln(y)}\over x}= xy$$
$$\dfrac {y'}{y}+\dfrac {\ln y}{x}=x$$
$$(\ln y)'+\dfrac {\ln y}{x}=x$$
It's a linear first order DE. Substitute $u=\ln y$
$$u'+\dfrac {u}{x}=x$$
$$xu'+u=x^2$$
$$(xu)'=x^2$$
Integrate.
$$\ln y =\dfrac {x^2}3+\dfrac {c_1}{x}$$
This answer dosent agree with Symbolab link but it agrees with [Wolfram Alpha's answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%20%2B%20%7B%7By%5Cln%28y%29%7D%2F%20x%7D%3D%20xy)
$$ y(x) =\exp {\left (\dfrac {x^2}3+\dfrac {c_1}{x}\right)}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your short answer and the new resource link!

Comment: You're welcome. It's obvious that the symbolab link gives an incorrect answer. This is not a Bernoulli's equation. @ATrashInTheWorld

Comment: Indeed, I was getting stuck pretty hard trying to play with Bernoulli.

Answer (score 2):

Well, we have the following first-order nonlinear ordinary differential equation:

$$\text{y}'\left(x\right)+\frac{\text{y}\left(x\right)\ln\left(\text{y}\left(x\right)\right)}{x}=x\text{y}\left(x\right)\tag1$$

This can be rewritten in the following form:

$$x^2\text{y}\left(x\right)-\text{y}\left(x\right)\ln\left(\text{y}\left(x\right)\right)-x\text{y}'\left(x\right)=0\tag2$$

Now, let $\text{R}\left(x,\text{y}\right)=x^2\text{y}-\text{y}\ln\left(\text{y}\right)$ and $\text{S}\left(x,\text{y}\right)=-x$. This is not an exact equation, because:

$$\left(\frac{\partial\text{R}\left(x,\text{y}\right)}{\partial\text{y}}=x^2-\ln\left(\text{y}\right)-1\right)\ne\left(-1=\frac{\partial\text{S}\left(x,\text{y}\right)}{\partial\text{y}}\right)\tag3$$

Find an integrating factor $\mu(\text{y})$ such that $\mu(\text{y})\text{R}\left(x,\text{y}\right)+\text{y}'\left(x\right)\text{S}\left(x,\text{y}\right)=0$ is exact. This means:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\text{y}}\left(\mu(\text{y})\text{R}\left(x,\text{y}\right)\right)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\mu(\text{y})\text{S}\left(x,\text{y}\right)\right)\tag4$$

Which gives:

$$\frac{\text{d}\mu(\text{y})}{\text{d}\text{y}}\left(\text{y}x^2-\text{y}\ln(\text{y})\right)+\mu(\text{y})\left(x^2-\ln(\text{y})-1\right)=-\mu(\text{y})\tag5$$

Isolte $\mu(\text{y})$ to the left-hand side:

$$\frac{\partial\mu(\text{y})}{\partial\text{y}}\cdot\frac{1}{\mu(\text{y})}=-\frac{1}{\text{y}}\tag6$$

Integrate both sides with respect to $\text{y}$:

$$\ln\left|\mu(\text{y})\right|=-\ln\left|\text{y}\right|\space\Longrightarrow\space\mu(\text{y})=\frac{1}{\text{y}}\tag7$$

So:

$$x^2-\ln\left(\text{y}\left(x\right)\right)-\frac{\text{d}\text{y}\left(x\right)}{\text{d}x}\cdot\frac{x}{\text{y}\left(x\right)}=0\tag8$$

> I let you finish.

Comment: What if $x=0$ and $y(x)=1$? Then, $(2)$ would still hold, but $(1)$ would contain the indeterminate form $\frac{0}{0}$, and hence be meaningless.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang If the ODE is solved completely you will see that we got a problem when $x\to0$.

Comment: That is a deep explanation, thank you very much!

Comment: @ATrashInTheWorld You're welcome, you can show your appreciation using the +1.